# ProgressBar inside ActionBar from fragment

Tags: android

I tried the following method but it does not work.

```
    getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your

```
getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

Is before your

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
```

Then call

```
getActionBar();
```

Before you use your

```
getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

How this works, is you are adding the window feature before your view is drawn. Then the getSupportActionBar() is used to just "open" the connection with your actionbar methods.